# How to Insert Shortcodes into Theme?

Tags: php, themes, shortcode

I have content locker plugin.

For locking contents, im using this shortcode:

**[wp-like-locker]**
Your locked content here...
**[/wp-like-locker]**

and I need lock every post on my blog. How could I instert this shortcodes into theme and lock:

**Thank you very very very much for your answer and time!**

Answer (score 2):

You can hardcode shortcodes into a theme using `do_shortcode`.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

```
echo do_shortcode('[wp-like-locker] Your locked content here... [/wp-like-locker]');
```

You will most likely want to replace the hard-coded "Your locked content here..." with the function that pulls the content from the editor, like `the_content`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

It might look like

```
  // the loop
  $content = get_the_content();
  echo do_shortcode('[wp-like-locker]' . $content .  '[/wp-like-locker]');
```

Comment: ...or just call the function attached to that shortcode directly and pass $content to it; no need for the extra overhead of do_shortcode...

Answer (score 1):

It would be both faster and cleaner to write a function to do this and put it in functions.php. It'd look like this (untested):

```
add_action( 'the_content', 'wpse49094_lock_content' );
function wpse49094_lock_content( $content ) {
    if( in_the_loop() ) {
        $content = do_shortcode( 'do_shortcode('[wp-like-locker]' . $content .  '[/wp-like-locker]');
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use do_shortcode() evaluate your short code.

you can place below code into sigle.php in your wordpress theme. And this will apply all of your posts those are using default template.

```
   <?php 
    get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); 

echo do_shortcode('[wp-like-locker]');

echo "Your locked content";

echo do_shortcode('[/wp-like-locker]');

?>
```

Comment: This code is wrong. Check out the [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) Codex page to see how to handle open-close shortcodes.